# Windows Photo Viewer needs more ram?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, images

**Update**

After extensive *Google* Searching, I found this "answer":

[Windows Photo Viewer - Bug](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproappcompat/thread/7b6ae08b-4b5c-443b-9d43-e87ca5e7aeb1)

**But** this is not a solution for me, after finding the same place in Windows 7 (instructions were for windows vista) The resulting box didn't have anything in it to delete.

**Original Question:**

Ok, so i went to open a picture with the `Windows Photo Viewer` (Default) application and it told me this:

> Windows Photo Viewer can't display this picture because there might not be enough memory available on your computer. Close some programs that you aren't using or free some hard disk space (if it's almost full), and then try again.

So looking at my 98% ram usage (thankyou VisualStudio x8 + SQL Server) I **rebooted** my computer.

Now this is my load:

[image: Commit Charge]

And this is my hard-disk loadout:

[image: HDD]

So now I go to load up that image again. **SAME MESSAGE**, what the heck? So apparantly 6gb isn't enough ram to open a 29k image that loads perfectly fine in `MSPaint`, `Paint.NET`, `Photoshop`

It's a `.png` and it's **not corrupt**. So my question is: what gives?

Comment: Is it only this picture that causes the memory issue?  Does this persist between reboots?

Comment: If you could upload the image somewhere and link to it here that would be helpfull.  For example there could be something wrong with the EXIF information if it has any, for example if that said the picture was huge the program may try to allocate memory depending on what that says.

Comment: Try Irfanview? (Regarding to the real issue.. never used the in-built viewer since even Picasa gives more feature, faster, easier.)

Comment: It persists through reboots, it happens on ANY picture. Including the two I posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found the solution!**

It has to do with *multiple videocards* (I run tripple-head @ work)

When I would load it up on a display on my secondary video card, I was presented with the above error. When i moved the window over to my primary video card: Presto! Image appeared.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with color profile of the jpg file.  You can try to change it in photoshop.  Go to Edit -> Convert to Profile and try a default profile.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the icc profile. change default profile to Afga : Swop Standard solved the issue.

Sadly doesn't work great with multiple monitors (only shows the image on monitor 1 and some image crash when u move to any of the other monitors).

Best solution is to get notepad++. Right click on all images with this issue and click edit with notepad++ (example pictures downloaded from skype chats all have this issue)

- Press <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd>
- Replace Find "ICC_PROFILE" Replace with "ICC_PROFILX"
- Replace in all documents
- File > Save all

Answer (score -1):

Use the below mentioned steps and check if this resolves your issue:

1. Click Start and go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display\Screen Resolution and click advanced settings.
2. Go into color management and click color management.
3. Under devices tick use my settings for this device and the highlight and delete the profile associated with this device

Comment: I'd be surprised if color profiles are responsible for this issue.