# Fully remove Windows Photo Viewer in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, windows-photo-viewer

How to fully uninstall [Windows Photo Viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Photo_Viewer) from Windows 10? It makes me mad.

I deleted directory *Windows Photo Viewer* both from **C:\Program Files (x86)** and **C:\Program Files** but it keeps opening my files anyway.

When I try to find out executable file location thru Task manager

[image]

it gives me **C:\Windows\System32\dllhost.exe**.

What is the proper way of uninstalling?

Comment: You mean the UWP app called Photos or the application Windows Photo Viewer (that is the default on W7)? Check this out: https://www.howtogeek.com/225844/how-to-make-windows-photo-viewer-your-default-image-viewer-on-windows-10/

Comment: He means Windows Photo Viewer. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/05/Windows_Photo_Viewer_Icon_on_Windows_7.png

Comment: Windows Photo viewer in actual is triggered by a DLL file. It is not a program. It appears that you have some sort of malware- have you checked for the same?

Comment: it is a program no matter how it is triggered, I have no malware

Comment: Windows photo viewer keeps hijacking default photo app. I want it wiped off the face of my computer, can I make NortonAV consider it a virus and delete it even if MS decides to re-install automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**: remove the DLL, preferably together with the install dir. In my case, PhotoViewer existed on both paths:

c:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer
c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Photo Viewer\

These directories and their contents were owned by *TrustedInstaller*, so I could not delete them using administrator privileges, because... well, because that's how MS thinks ownership and priviliges should work.

So I had to set the ownership of these dirs to *Administrators* and then give full permissions to *Administrators* (recursively). (There are pretty good guides on how to do this on the Internet, so I won't bore you with that.)

After that, I only managed to remove the exe and dll files from here, de en-US etc. localization dirs remained, with all the *.mui files in them. Not elegant, but the general goal of removing PhotoViewer.dll was still achieved.

**Step 2**: clear associated keys from the registry.

regedit.exe > Edit > Find > PhotoViewer.dll

I had a single hit. Again I had to assume ownership and give full access to Administrators. After that, I managed to remove the key containing the path to the dll.

[Now my original problem is fixed, the deprecated and buggy **Windows** Photo Viewer won't stand in the way of using **Microsoft** Photo Viewer by default.](https://superuser.com/questions/1509194)

Comment: I wasn't able to complete the second step, number of nodes related to PhotoViewer.dll in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` are not possible to delete, anyway thanks for the comprehensive approach

Comment: I got probably 20 hits. You have to take ownership in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT as only TrusterInstaller has access by default. You can then change permissions to full for Administrators and delete.