# windows photo viewer can't open picture

Tags: desktop-computer

i encountered below issue on windows 7 .

the default App - windows photo viewer can't open some JPG format file from my Android phone and got below error message.

"windows photo viewer can't display this picture because there might not be enough memory available on your computer. close some programs that you aren't using or free some hard disk space."

but this is not the fact , actually machine has much of free memory.

the strange thing is that the same file can show its thumbnail and also can be opened by App paint.exe

could you please help ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take a look at this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1509194/windows-photo-viewer-cant-run-because-not-enough-memory)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [this fix](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/message-windows-photo-viewer-cant-display-this/a58be541-4769-477f-87d9-016a7e61ef6b)?

"Click Start and go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display\Screen Resolution and click advanced settings.

Go into Color Management tab and click on Color Management.

Under Devices tab tick "Use My Settings" for this device.

Highlight and delete the profile associated with this device.

Check the images."

Comment: tried and no use.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 7:

**Right click on desktop: Screen Resolution -> Advanced Settings -> Tab-Color Management -> Color Management -> Tab-Advanced: Device profile**

[For me working profile: Agfa swop standart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAWtq.png)